# Bind more controller properties to one attribute using HTMLBars

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

is this correct or is there any other solution?

```
<input disabled={{model.isnValid}} disabled={{isSaving}}>
```

I know that I can create new CP and depend on **model.isnValid** and **isSaving**, but I want to know if there is any other solutions.

Thank you for advices

Comment: Nope, using a computed property is the right way to do this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a computed property is probably best here.  Another potential solution is [ember-truth-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers) which would allow you to write code such as:

```
<input disabled={{or model.isInvalid model.isSaving}}>
```

I use ember-truth-helpers a lot, but that just looks weird and I wouldn't recommend it.